# I'm alerting strings, but not returning

Tags: javascript

I was told that *this code is alerting the strings, but not returning*. I'm sorry, complete beginner...I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, every test I run says it's good. Thanks

```
function myFavFood() {
}   

var food;

if (food == "pizza") {
  alert("I love Pizza");
} 
else if (food == "Hot pockets") {
  alert("hot pockets woo");
}
else {
  alert("I have bad taste in foods");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Define *returning*, that function does nothing, the *if* construct exists outside of it. What do you need to do?

Comment: `myFavFood` is never called. Assuming the code below belongs inside it, what is it *supposed* to return?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
function myFavFood(food) {
  if (food == "pizza") { alert("I love Pizza"); } 
  else if (food == "Hot pockets") { alert("hot pockets woo"); }
  else { alert("I have bad taste in foods"); } 
}
```

Comment: This code block still doesn't return values, although it is slightly improved, in that it now has the `if`s inside the function

Comment: I assume the answer of @yochannah answers you.  (Accept it).

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple, really: instead of `alert(something)`, to return it, you need to simple type `return aVariable;`

e.g.

```
function myFavFoodReturn(food) {

var response;

 if (food == "pizza") {
  response = "I love Pizza";
 } 
else if (food == "Hot pockets") {
  response = "hot pockets woo";
 }
 else {
  response = "I have bad taste in foods";
 } 
  return response; //this returns but doesn't alert. 
}
```

Have a play with alerting vs returning here: https://jsbin.com/mufuba/2/edit?js,console

===

The difference is in how the variable is handled.

alerting a variable merely shows it on the screen, whereas returning it will not show it on the screen. You could think of it as the difference between sending a letter in the post physically (returning the letter) and simply showing someone the letter, but not giving it to them (alerting it).
Here's a quick demo of the differences:

```
var someVariable = "this is an awesome variable";

function alertSomething() {
  alert(someVariable);
}

function returnSomething(){
  return someVariable;
}


var a = alertSomething();

var b = returnSomething();

//this will output '"the alert method doesn't return a value: undefined"':
console.log("the alert method doesn't return a value, see: " + a);

//this will output '"but the return method does: this is an awesome variable"'
console.log("but the return method does: " + b);
```

JSBIN working demo: https://jsbin.com/ruvaxi/1/edit?js,console

---

Note that typically a return statement halts execution of a function, so it needs to be the last thing you want to happen in a function. e.g.

```
function myFunction(a) {
   return a*2; //this line returns the 'a' argument, but doubled
   alert('awesomesauce');  //this line will never run, because of the return.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the function `myFavFood` is never called, so it will never be executed.
However, this part of the code:

```
var response;

 if (food == "pizza") {
  response = "I love Pizza";
 } 
else if (food == "Hot pockets") {
  response = "hot pockets woo";
 }
 else {
  response = "I have bad taste in foods";
 } 
  return response; //this returns but doesn't alert. 
}
```

executes with no problem just because is not a part of the function (You need to put the code inside the { } ), that part of the code is "global" and executes when the browser opens your page.

If you wanna call the function and execute the code **INSIDE HER** you need to do this:

```
    function myFavFood() {
                var food;

                if (food == "pizza") {
                  alert("I love Pizza");
                } 
                else if (food == "Hot pockets") {
                  alert("hot pockets woo");
                }
                else {
                  alert("I have bad taste in foods");
                } 
            }
**myFavFood()**
```

(Note that the code is now inside the {} keys, and if you wanna call and execute the code you need to type "functionNameAnd()".

And for the final part, if you wanna return something just type `return` and the variable or element you wanna return to something outside the function:

Like this:

```
function myFavFood() {
            var food;

            if (food == "pizza") {
              alert("I love Pizza");
              return food;
            } 
            else if (food == "Hot pockets") {
              alert("hot pockets woo");
              return food;
            }
            else {
              alert("I have bad taste in foods");
            } 
        }
```

Now, if you call the function with a variable, that variable will take the value of the returned element.

So, if you do:

var something = myFavFood(), and the food variable was pizza, the function will return "pizza", and the variable something will have the value pizza.